# Proof of the finite subgroup criterion

Tags: group-theory

For a finite group $G$, a subgroup H exists iff $ \forall x,y \in H, xy \in\  H$

Now the forward implication is obvious

For the converse, my professor started with using induction to proof that

$x^{a} \in H$ $ \forall a \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0} $

Then choose $a = |H| + 1$ then by pigeon hole principle there exist some $c < b$ s.t. $x^{b} = x^{c}$

He then writes

$ 1_{identity} = x^{b} (x^{c})^{-1}  = x^{b-c} x^c (x^c)^{-1}  = x^{b-c} \in H $ (Then $H$ is closed under identity)

He then goes on to proof closed under inversion by

$x x^{b-c - 1} = x^{b-c} = 1$

And so we get the subgroup criteria for $H$

**Question :**

Proofing the converse means that $H$ need not have the inverse of an element yet the step of using

$x^{b} = x^{c}$ then $x^{b} (x^{c})^{-1} = 1_{identity}$ already seems to assume that the inverse of $c$ exists and it is in fact $x^{b}$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the claim isn't true: take $H = \varnothing$.

Comment: In the end you wrote about inverse of $c$, you probably mean inverse of $x^c$. We know that the inverse of $x^c$ exists in $G$. (Since $G$ is a group.)

Answer (score 1):

It does not assume the existence of the inverse. Since $x$ is not the identity, $b-c \gt 1 \implies b-c-1 \gt 0 \implies x^{b-c-1} ∈ H$.This proves that $H$ is closed and has an inverse for each element.

Comment: while $b - c > 1$ but in the proof we need $x^{b} = x^{c} \implies x^{b-c} = 1$ which seems to be precisely the inverse operation. I think this is fine because while the converse is to use closed under multiplication to proof the finite subgroup, we still have that $H  \subset G$ and so for every element in H there exists the inverse and the inverse operation is still well defined...

Comment: The argument of $x^{b-c} = 1$ is done in $G$ where we can safely assume the existence of $x^{-c}$. Since $b-c$ is positive, $1 ∈ H$, and the proof follows.

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite follow what you did. There's an extra variable or something.

Here's perhaps a simpler approach.

Let $g\in H$.  Say $g$ has order $n$ (since $G$ is finite).  Then since $g^n=e,$ we have $g^{n-1}=g^{-1}.$

But $g^{n-1}\in H$, by closedness.

$\therefore H$ is closed under inverses.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, now I realise that I did not state that $ c, b \epsilon \mathbb{Z}_{>0}  $  When proofing the converse we still have that $ x , y \epsilon G$ so their inverse exists and the operation is still well-defined for the elements in H . Your approach seems to already assume that $g^{n} \epsilon H$ which is not the case when proofing the converse.

Comment: There was a typo.   Since $g\in H$ and $H$ is closed,  it *is* the case that $g^n\in H.$

Answer (score -1):

I think you have misunderstood something. If I consider the $G=(\mathbb{Z},+)$ then according to the condition mentioned in your first line $H=(\mathbb{N},+)$ is a subgroup as it is closed under addition, but no identity exist. Which means $H$ is not a group and hence not a subgroup.

The actual statement is "A subset $H\subset G$ of a group $(G,\circ)$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff $\forall a,b\in H,\ ab^{-1}\in H$". Have a look at the [link](https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/group-theory/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-a-subgroup.html#google_vignette:%7E:text=following%20two%20theorems.-,Theorem%201%3A%20A%20subset,.,-Thus%20the%20condition).

Comment: The question asked for the case where $G$ is finite, in which case the statement is true

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you pointed out that closed under multiplication is not sufficient for infinite sets